# Mongoose 4 sockets closing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a script that I use to save all my models (for ex to reindex). I am getting socket closing errors after a couple of hundred saves (Ihave 900 total). I recently upgraded to Mongoose 4.2.3 from 3.x.x and started seeing these errors. I am not sure what else to go on.

Errors:

```
{ [MongoError: server ds0133252-a0.mongolab.com:133252 sockets closed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server ds051252-a0.mongolab.com:51252 sockets closed' }
{ [MongoError: server ds0133252-a0.mongolab.com:133252 sockets closed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  ....
```

The script is pretty basic:

```
var mongoose = require(mongoose),
  Product = require('../models/product'),
  config = require('config');

mongoose.connect(config.db.mongo.connection, config.db.mongo.options);

Product.find(function(err, products) {
  products.forEach(function(p) {
    p.markModified('description');
    p.save(function(e, product) {
      if(e) console.log(e);
      console.log(product.id);
     });
  });
});
```

The model is pretty complex but hasn't changed in a while. I have disabled the "save" middleware with same errors so it should be pretty standard.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an async flow control library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to use an *async* iterator that lets you limit the number of concurrent `save` operations.

In this case, [`async.eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) would be a good fit (doc link is to `each`, scroll down to see the `eachLimit` variant). For example, to limit the iteration to no more than 5 concurrent saves:

```
Product.find(function(err, products) {
  async.eachLimit(products, 5, function(p, callback) {
    p.markModified('description');
    p.save(function(e, product) {
      if(e) console.log(e);
      console.log(product.id);
      callback(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Note that the `callback` parameter of `eachLimit` must be called when the `save` completes so that the library knows that particular iteration is complete.

Comment: Interesting solution! How did you know that too many concurrent queries would cause the sockets close error?

Comment: @Zugwalt Well, since I never heard back from the OP, I can't say if it actually worked for them. But I've seen similar issues in the past.